# Unsuccessful attempt to repair permissions with OnyX on El Capitan

Tags: macos, disk-utility, permission, maintenance

I'm trying to execute the maintenance  script in [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/) and I keep on getting the same errors at each pass:

- Permissions in the **X11** folder are constantly being repaid *(i.e. OnyX is showing that it repaired the same permissions at each pass)*.
- OnyX is not able to repair permissions in the `usr/share/zoneinfo/` folder

---

## OnyX log

```
volume_arg = /
Starting argv pass #2...
Processing files from package com.apple.update.firmwareupdate...
Processing files from package com.apple.pkg.update.os.10.11.2.15C50...
Processing files from package com.apple.pkg.X11redirect...
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/Xephyr", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/Xephyr".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/Xfake", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/Xfake".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/Xnest", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/Xnest".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/Xquartz", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/Xquartz".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/Xvfb", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/Xvfb".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/appres", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/appres".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/atobm", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/atobm".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/bdftopcf", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/bdftopcf".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/bdftruncate", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/bdftruncate".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/bitmap", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/bitmap".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/bmtoa", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/bmtoa".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/cxpm", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/cxpm".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/editres", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/editres".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/fc-cache", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/fc-cache".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/fc-cat", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/fc-cat".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/fc-list", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/fc-list".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/fc-match", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/fc-match".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/fc-query", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/fc-query".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/fc-scan", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/fc-scan".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/font_cache", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/font_cache".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/fonttosfnt", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/fonttosfnt".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/freetype-config", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/freetype-config".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/fslsfonts", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/fslsfonts".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/fstobdf", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/fstobdf".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/gccmakedep", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/gccmakedep".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/glxgears", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/glxgears".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/glxinfo", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/glxinfo".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/iceauth", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/iceauth".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/ico", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/ico".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/koi8rxterm", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/koi8rxterm".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/libpng15-config", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/libpng15-config".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/listres", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/listres".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/lndir", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/lndir".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/luit", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/luit".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/makedepend", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/makedepend".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/mkfontdir", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/mkfontdir".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/mkfontscale", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/mkfontscale".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/oclock", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/oclock".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/sessreg", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/sessreg".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/setxkbmap", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/setxkbmap".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/showfont", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/showfont".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/showrgb", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/showrgb".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/smproxy", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/smproxy".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/startx", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/startx".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/sxpm", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/sxpm".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/twm", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/twm".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/ucs2any", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/ucs2any".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/uxterm", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/uxterm".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/viewres", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/viewres".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/x11perf", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/x11perf".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/x11perfcomp", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/x11perfcomp".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xauth", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xauth".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xbacklight", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xbacklight".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xcalc", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xcalc".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xclipboard", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xclipboard".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xclock", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xclock".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xcmsdb", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xcmsdb".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xconsole", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xconsole".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xcursorgen", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xcursorgen".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xcutsel", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xcutsel".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xditview", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xditview".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xdm", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xdm".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xdmshell", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xdmshell".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xdpr", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xdpr".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xdpyinfo", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xdpyinfo".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xedit", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xedit".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xev", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xev".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xeyes", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xeyes".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xfd", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xfd".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xfontsel", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xfontsel".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xfs", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xfs".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xfsinfo", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xfsinfo".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xgamma", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xgamma".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xgc", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xgc".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xhost", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xhost".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xinit", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xinit".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xinput", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xinput".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xkbbell", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xkbbell".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xkbcomp", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xkbcomp".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xkbevd", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xkbevd".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xkbprint", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xkbprint".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xkbvleds", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xkbvleds".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xkbwatch", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xkbwatch".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xkeystone", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xkeystone".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xkill", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xkill".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xload", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xload".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xlogo", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xlogo".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xlsatoms", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xlsatoms".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xlsclients", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xlsclients".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xlsfonts", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xlsfonts".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xmag", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xmag".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xman", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xman".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xmessage", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xmessage".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xmh", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xmh".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xmodmap", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xmodmap".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xmore", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xmore".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xpr", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xpr".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xprop", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xprop".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xrandr", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xrandr".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xrdb", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xrdb".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xrefresh", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xrefresh".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xscope", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xscope".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xset", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xset".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xsetmode", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xsetmode".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xsetpointer", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xsetpointer".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xsetroot", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xsetroot".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xsm", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xsm".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xstdcmap", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xstdcmap".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xterm", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xterm".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xvinfo", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xvinfo".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xwd", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xwd".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xwininfo", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xwininfo".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xwud", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xwud".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/lib/libXaw.6.dylib", should be -rwxr-xr-x , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/lib/libXaw.6.dylib".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/lib/libXaw.7.dylib", should be -rwxr-xr-x , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/lib/libXaw.7.dylib".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/lib/libxcb-atom.1.dylib", should be -rwxr-xr-x , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/lib/libxcb-atom.1.dylib".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/lib/libxcb-aux.0.dylib", should be -rwxr-xr-x , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/lib/libxcb-aux.0.dylib".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/lib/libxcb-event.1.dylib", should be -rwxr-xr-x , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/lib/libxcb-event.1.dylib".
Processing files from package com.apple.pkg.Essentials...
    Permissions differ on "usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Belfast", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Unable to set owner & group on "usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Belfast". Error 1: Operation not permitted
    Unable to set permissions on "usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Belfast". Error 1: Operation not permitted
    Permissions differ on "usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Guernsey", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Unable to set owner & group on "usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Guernsey". Error 1: Operation not permitted
    Unable to set permissions on "usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Guernsey". Error 1: Operation not permitted
    Permissions differ on "usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Isle_of_Man", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Unable to set owner & group on "usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Isle_of_Man". Error 1: Operation not permitted
    Unable to set permissions on "usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Isle_of_Man". Error 1: Operation not permitted
    Permissions differ on "usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Jersey", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Unable to set owner & group on "usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Jersey". Error 1: Operation not permitted
    Unable to set permissions on "usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Jersey". Error 1: Operation not permitted
    Permissions differ on "usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Unable to set owner & group on "usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London". Error 1: Operation not permitted
    Unable to set permissions on "usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London". Error 1: Operation not permitted
    Permissions differ on "usr/share/zoneinfo/GB", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Unable to set owner & group on "usr/share/zoneinfo/GB". Error 1: Operation not permitted
    Unable to set permissions on "usr/share/zoneinfo/GB". Error 1: Operation not permitted
    Permissions differ on "usr/share/zoneinfo/GB-Eire", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Unable to set owner & group on "usr/share/zoneinfo/GB-Eire". Error 1: Operation not permitted
    Unable to set permissions on "usr/share/zoneinfo/GB-Eire". Error 1: Operation not permitted
Processing files from package com.apple.pkg.BaseSystemResources...
Processed 423406 paths from 5 packages.
```

---

How can I make sure that the all permissions are fixed once for all?

---

### OnyX - second log

Just to illustrate the problem further, nothing changes after I run OnyX second time. It produces the same log:

```
volume_arg = /
Starting argv pass #2...
Processing files from package com.apple.update.firmwareupdate...
Processing files from package com.apple.pkg.update.os.10.11.2.15C50...
Processing files from package com.apple.pkg.X11redirect...
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/Xephyr", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/Xephyr".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/Xfake", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/Xfake".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/Xnest", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/Xnest".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/Xquartz", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/Xquartz".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/Xvfb", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/Xvfb".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/appres", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/appres".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/atobm", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/atobm".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/bdftopcf", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/bdftopcf".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/bdftruncate", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/bdftruncate".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/bitmap", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/bitmap".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/bmtoa", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/bmtoa".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/cxpm", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/cxpm".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/editres", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/editres".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/fc-cache", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/fc-cache".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/fc-cat", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/fc-cat".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/fc-list", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/fc-list".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/fc-match", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/fc-match".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/fc-query", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/fc-query".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/fc-scan", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/fc-scan".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/font_cache", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/font_cache".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/fonttosfnt", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/fonttosfnt".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/freetype-config", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/freetype-config".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/fslsfonts", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/fslsfonts".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/fstobdf", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/fstobdf".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/gccmakedep", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/gccmakedep".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/glxgears", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/glxgears".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/glxinfo", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/glxinfo".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/iceauth", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/iceauth".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/ico", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/ico".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/koi8rxterm", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/koi8rxterm".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/libpng15-config", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/libpng15-config".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/listres", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/listres".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/lndir", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/lndir".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/luit", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/luit".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/makedepend", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/makedepend".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/mkfontdir", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/mkfontdir".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/mkfontscale", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/mkfontscale".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/oclock", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/oclock".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/sessreg", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/sessreg".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/setxkbmap", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/setxkbmap".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/showfont", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/showfont".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/showrgb", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/showrgb".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/smproxy", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/smproxy".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/startx", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/startx".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/sxpm", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/sxpm".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/twm", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/twm".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/ucs2any", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/ucs2any".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/uxterm", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/uxterm".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/viewres", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/viewres".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/x11perf", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/x11perf".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/x11perfcomp", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/x11perfcomp".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xauth", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xauth".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xbacklight", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xbacklight".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xcalc", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xcalc".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xclipboard", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xclipboard".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xclock", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xclock".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xcmsdb", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xcmsdb".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xconsole", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xconsole".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xcursorgen", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xcursorgen".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xcutsel", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xcutsel".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xditview", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xditview".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xdm", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xdm".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xdmshell", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xdmshell".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xdpr", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xdpr".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xdpyinfo", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xdpyinfo".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xedit", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xedit".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xev", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xev".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xeyes", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xeyes".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xfd", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xfd".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xfontsel", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xfontsel".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xfs", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xfs".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xfsinfo", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
    Repaired "usr/X11/bin/xfsinfo".
    Permissions differ on "usr/X11/bin/xgamma", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .


...
```

*Long truncated due to the space limit.*

Comment: Did you give it admin perms at launch?

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, I did. It always asks for the admin password after launching.

Comment: I wonder whether it's hitting SIP. Just trying something, brb...

Comment: It's not an actual perms error, it's `link` vs `real` filetype - see http://superuser.com/questions/515048/verifying-permissions-on-osx

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks very much, [this](http://superuser.com/a/515276/270754) appears to be the useful suggestion. What would be the wise way to approach this problem? Shall I just ignore it?

Comment: I'd ignore it.. My X11 is exactly the same, same errors on Onyx.

Comment: Have you used Disk Utility to repair permissions and gotten the same results?

Comment: @user3439894 No, apparently this is [no longer possible](http://www.imore.com/say-goodbye-repairing-file-permissions-el-capitan) in *DU* available with *El Capitan*.

Comment: Not running 10.11, didn't know it was removed.  It can be done by command line using `repair_packages` however that's probably what OnyX is calling to do it. You might want to look at: [How to Verify & Repair Permissions in OS X El Capitan](http://osxdaily.com/2015/11/04/verify-repair-permissions-mac-os-x/)

Comment: @user3439894 It returned the same output

Comment: Well then I have to agree with Tetsujin and not worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by user164077, this is protected by your computer's System Integrity Protection.

SIP is a security measure to prevent any User up to and including root (and thereby most malware) from modifying system files.

To disable:

1. Boot into Recovery Mode (Hold Command+R while turning on Mac).
2. Open Terminal (Click Utilities > Terminal).
3. Type: `csrutil disable`
4. Restart your computer, and SIP will be disabled.

The "usr" folder should now be accessible by OnyX.

Answer (score -1):

It's normal. The usr folder is protected by the SIP.